# Using SVG with PNG fall back in img tags depending on browser without javascript or PHP

Tags: html, browser, svg

I know there are several topics on this subject, but ultimately, all the answers seem to suggest using modernizr or some javascript code. I think the biggest reason to include a png fallback is for IE8 and lower. I was wondering why nobody seems to be using the following code.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><img src="img.png" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><img src="img.svg" /><!--<![endif]-->
```

First question, is this bad? Is the industry standard way to use modernizr and javascript?

Second question, I noticed that the second line seems to be shown for other browsers like Chrome and Firefox beside IE 9 and IE 10. That's exactly the behavior I wanted, but it seems weird. Is it supposed to be like that?

Third question, I've googled and can't seem to find a place where all the comment functions like [if...] are explained. Are there other functions than [if...]? Is there [if...then]?

Comment: There a tutorial here that shows another approach: http://davidensinger.com/2013/04/inline-svg-with-png-fallback/  I actually like your approach more, I think it's more readable, although I'm also surprised that Chrome and FF parse the IE if comments.

Comment: The trick you are using (massaging the end comment) to make the second line visible to other browsers, may not be reliable.  It is probably better to be more explicit than to use somewhat kludgey tricks like that.

Comment: The inline SVG with foreignObject method suggested by @Nathan seems to work everywhere. However, if you prefer using a linked file, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539354/svg-for-images-in-browsers-with-png-fallback/21502410#21502410).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<object data="img.svg" width="200px" height="50px" type="image/svg+xml">
   <img src="img.png" width="200" height="50">
</object>
```

Comment: According to this question the height attribute might not work in Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539354/svg-for-images-in-browsers-with-png-fallback?rq=1

Comment: If you see that webkit height problem, try the possible solutions from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372177/how-do-i-scale-a-linked-image-inside-an-svg-from-top-currently-scaling-from-cen

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. IE8 and IE7 show an empty white box in place of the `object` tag, ignoring the image inside.