# How to scale an SVG with <image> tag fallback?

Tags: css, html, image, internet-explorer, svg

I am examining how to add external SVG files in a responsive manner, and fell for the [SVG image tag trick](http://lynn.ru/examples/svg/en.html), because it doesn't require JavaScript.

(The SVG has been 'washed' with scour, thus being stripped of height/width attributes, and `viewBox` being added, as recommended.)

The problem is that this technique seems to require a `height` and `width` attribute to work, on the `image` tag, which isn't responsive. Suggested syntax is:

```
<svg width="200px" height="100px">
    <image xlink:href="logo.svg" src="logo.png" width="200px" height="100px"/>
</svg>
```

However, setting relative dimensions, like so:

```
<svg style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <image xlink:href="logo.svg" src="logo.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
```

.. makes the SVG responsive, however renders the `<image>` element incorrectly (or, not as expected anyway). This can be fixed by adding `preserveAspectRatio` and `viewBox` attributes:

```
<svg style="width:100%; height:100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <image xlink:href="logo.svg" src="logo.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
```

Now everything works as expected in all major browsers, except that in IE9-11, the problem now lies with `<svg>` tag: it's not wrapped around the `<image>` tag.

Been playing around with various combinations, like omitting the `<svg>`'s height attribute, but to no avail.

Has anyone solved this without using JavaScript or conditional statements?

Note: Other methods to achieve the same is of course welcome (that is, responsive, external SVG file, working fallback, and without using JavaScript)
Note 2: The described method does not fallback gracefully in Safari on IOS 5 either.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on the same issue today and ran across your question hoping for an answer.

Check out this code for the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/ECTBL/

The trick was having the right attributes in my SVG file i.e.

```
height="..." 
width="..." 
viewBox="..." 
xml:space="preserve"
```

When I saved the file from illustrator, it was missing a height and width attributes in the SVG file.

Finally, you'll need the following CSS for it to work:

This is for a bug in webkit

```
svg { max-height: 100%; }
```

And of course, this makes the image stretch.

```
img { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Using the `img` tag is another method, which does not provide a fallback in browsers not understanding SVG.

Comment: It works fine for me, you need to specify an image in the onerror attribute like so:

    <img src="image.svg" width="100%" onerror="this.src='FALLBACK.png';this.onerror=null;">

Comment: I've made a few more changes, this should be all that is needed now - http://jsfiddle.net/Yq5GB/

Comment: Other methods are welcome, but please read my criteria for such a method (no JS is was of them)