# Gaps when trying to align SVGs with an HTML element

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to align a couple of SVG elements with a SPAN. It looks fine with Atom's HTML preview, but under Chrome and Safari, there a gap between the SVGs and the span that I can't account for.

http://jsbin.com/pawupu/edit?html,css,output

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

div.digitDiv {
   font-size:10vw;
   font-family: monospace;
   display:inline-block;
   width:1em;
   margin-left:2em;
  border:1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
}

span.digit {
    border:1px solid green;
}

svg {
    border:1px solid blue;
    width: 5vw;
    fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title>SVG, why you no align?</title>
</head>


<body>

<!-- this works! -->
<div class="digitDiv">
  <span class="digit">1</span>
  <span class="digit">2</span>
  <span class="digit">3</span>
</div>

<!-- this doesn't! -->
<div class="digitDiv">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M50,0 100,100 0,100 Z"></path></svg>
 <span class="digit">1</span>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M0,0 100,0 50,100 Z"></path></svg>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I could manually alter the SVGs' positions via CSS, but I'm wondering if I'm overlooking something else.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very similar question to yours  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533043/how-to-remove-the-space-between-the-svg-and-the-td-in-html5)  and the answer works for you as well.

As said on the linked answer, "SVG is inline and inside of a table cell", so you need to add a `display:block` statement in the CSS for the `svg` and fix the horizontal positions manually.

Comment: OP just needs to make the `svg` and `span` in `.digitDiv` `display: block`. http://jsbin.com/tumujojeni/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

You could try floating the elements within .digitDiv.

```
span.digit {
    border:1px solid green;
    float:left

}

svg {
    border:1px solid blue;
    width: 5vw;
    fill: #000;
    float:left
}
```