# How do you access the contents of an SVG file in an <img> element?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Say you have this in your HTML:

`<img src='example.svg' />`

How would you access the contents ( ie. `<rect>, <circle>, <ellipse>`, etc.. ) of the example.svg via JavaScript?

Answer (score 42):

It's not possible to get the DOM of a referenced svg from the `img` element.

If you use `<object>`, `<embed>` or `<iframe>` however then you can use `.contentDocument` (preferred) to get the referenced svg, or `.getSVGDocument` which may be more compatible with old svg plugins.

Here's an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html) showing how to get the DOM of a referenced svg.

Comment: is the link to the example broken ?

Comment: @Goswin odd, looks like a web server glitch, the files are there... hopefully it'll start working soon.

Comment: Note that `.contentDocument` can access an external SVG file referenced by `<object>` and `<iframe>` elements, but not by `<embed>` elements, while `.getSVGDocument()`can access the same from all three. However, `.getSVGDocument()` [is now deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceGetSVGDocument) and so should only be used if processing `<embed>` elements is actually required. Note also that `.contentDocument` is a (non-function) property while `.getSVGDocument()` is a method (and thus requires the parentheses).

Comment: Anyone needing to use the `<img/>` tag (e.g. if you don't have control over the SVG resource) may want to know about appending [SVG Fragement identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers), e.g. "`<img src="myimage.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))" />`", which lets you control the aspect ratio, `viewBox`, etc the same as with inline SVG definitions.

Comment: document.querySelector('#id-of-object-containing-svg').contentDocument.querySelector('svg').outerHTML

Answer (score 17):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. The external SVG is not part of the DOM in the way an inline SVG is, and I don't believe you can access the SVG DOM tree from the loading document.

What you *can* do is load the SVG as XML, using an AJAX request, and insert it into the DOM as an inline SVG you can then walk and manipulate. [This D3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/1014829) demonstrates the technique. I think the `d3.xml()` function used here is more or less equivalent to jQuery's `$.ajax()` with `dataType: "xml"`.

Comment: That or use an `<object>`, `<embed>` or `<iframe>` tag for loading the svg, those all allow you to get the DOM.

Comment: Really? I'm playing around with it a little bit, and neither jQuery nor `element.childNodes` seem to show any exposed SVG DOM. Do you have an example?

Comment: Examples: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html

Comment: Thanks, that's very cool - had never heard of `getSVGDocument`. You should submit as an answer - I think it's a simpler and more straightforward method than mine.

Comment: nrabinowitz: Agreed, Erik Dahlstroms example here is a great solution - you get bounty points by proxy!

Comment: this question has a very popular answer for how to convert an img which is SVG to an SVG inline http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement

Answer (score 2):

No, not possible but you can convert `<img>` to `<svg>` as mentioned [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27019034/1292050) (same code available below) and you can access the nodes of svg in the DOM.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#img').each(function(){
            var img         = $(this);
            var image_uri   = img.attr('src');

            $.get(image_uri, function(data) {
                var svg = $(data).find('svg');
                svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
                img.replaceWith(svg);
            }, 'xml');

        });
    });
</script>


<img id='img' src="my.svg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using inlining of SVG into CSS `url(data:...)` or just using `url(*.svg)` background, you can embed them into DOM with [svg-embed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-embed).

Support Chrome 11+, Safari 5+, FireFox 4+ and IE9+.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a back end language that can go fetch the file and insert it, at least you can clean up the authoring experience. Like:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("kiwi.svg"); ?>
```

A little PHP-specific thing here… it was demonstrated to me that file_get_contents() is the correct function here, not include() or include_once() as I have used before. Specifically because SVG sometimes is exported with  that as the opening line, which will cause the PHP parser to choke on it.

(Information taken out of [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/))