# dynamically change the colour of an embed svg image

Tags: jquery, dynamic, colors, svg

I am trying to implement an SVG logo and would like to dynamically change the colour of it on an event.

At the moment I have simply embedded it:

```
<embed class="logo" src="images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" />
```

I then use this piece of jQuery to switch the embed for an img tag for webkit browser support.

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
            $(".logo").replaceWith("<img class=logo src=images/logo.svg type=image/svg+xml pluginspage=http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/ />")
            }
```

Is it possible to manipulate the fill colour of the SVG using this implementation?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can get the referenced svg's DOM from the <embed> element, but not from the <img> element. Also see [How do you access the contents of an SVG file in an <img> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102528/how-do-you-access-the-contents-of-an-svg-file-in-an-img-element)

Answer (score 1):

There is a getSVGDocument method suggested by other questions/answers but it appears to work only in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/Kqd89/

Either I'm doing something wrong or the answer to the question is No.

Comment: See http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html, which shows getSVGDocument working just fine in all browsers.

Comment: Ok, then I must be doing something wrong in that fiddle. Probably worth another question :))