# Maintain stroke weight of SVG Image

Tags: html, css, svg

If I had an SVG image like this:

```
<img src="image.svg">
```

Would there be some sort of attribute that I can implement to main the SVG's stroke weight? Something like this:

```
<img src="image.svg" stroke="2px">
```

To get this type of desired effect:
[image: SVG scaling simulation]

Is this possible? If not, will this ever be possible for SVG or do they just not work like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` as demonstrated [here](http://schepers.cc/svg/vectoreffects/nonscalingstroke.svg)

Comment: This only applies to the SVG element, not an image correct? We are talking strictly images that are SVGs here.

Comment: Seems to work just fine on Firefox for me: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpojmut9/)

Comment: I don't see how you are applying that attribute in this fiddle.

Comment: Well, there's no attribute I know off usable on the img-tag itself, but you could just [embed the svg as an object or iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102528/how-do-you-access-the-contents-of-an-svg-file-in-an-img-element) and change the attribute in the SVG dom