# Img.svg to svg tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an svg image i.e img src="image.svg". how to make this tag to be converted to svg tags in browser. I just tried in image tag but browser renders it as image tag only not as svg

Comment: To render and svg you should use `<svg>` tag. If you have an svg file open it in notepad and copy the contents in the `<svg> </svg>`

Comment: Ya i knew it. worked well for me. But my concern any solution for auto conversion

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102528/how-do-you-access-the-contents-of-an-svg-file-in-an-img-element hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using img use `<embed>` or `<object>` tags and try either `.contentDocument` or `getSVGDocument()` to get the contents of the svg file.

See the source code of this link for a live example http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html