# Dynamically load svg and access content to change fillColor

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

```
        var img = document.createElement('object');
        img.data = 'texture.svg';
        img.type = 'image/svg+xml';
        img.onload = function () {
            console.log('cont: '+this.contentDocument.getElementById('K3').id);
            this.contentDocument.getElementById('K3').style.fillColor = 'yellow';
        };
```

I would like to load *svg* file which is texture for Three.js mesh.
Then I want to access element inside SCG with id *K3* and change its *fillColor* to another.
I tried with img but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102528/how-do-you-access-the-contents-of-an-svg-file-in-an-img-element) someone advice to use `<object>`
In my example *onload* method is not executed.

Comment: take inspiration from: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thank you, it is an impressive method to manipulate svg.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to use it for changing svg in texture container within Three.js  
**BTW. I have another idea to load SVG into canvas and use CanvasTexture in Three.js. If it succeeds I will write a solution here.**

Comment: yes, like many older libraries that can't deal with modern shadowDOM, that is a Three.js limitation, not a Web Components limitation

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Are you able to recommend not old alternative for Three.js?

Comment: No, alas I am not