# Full width and height SVG

Tags: css, svg

The dilemma: make a full window svg image that fills WITH aspect distortion, WITHOUT using an SVG tag. Why no svg tag? Because I intend on swapping out the SVG later (if not frequently) in the life of the page, and I have not found an easy way to do that.

The failed attempts:

```html
  <!-- for the record, my style are in a css file, 
       for example purposes they are style attrs-->

  <!-- Working in Webkit but not in firefox, in firefox blocks stretching 
       and places the svg in the middle of the tag-->
  <img src="my.svg" style="width:100%;height:100%;
       position:fixed;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;" />

  <!-- Both Webkit and Firefox block distortion, so the svg 
       appears centered in the div rather than conforming to the div-->
  <div style="width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed;top:0;
       left:0;bottom:0;right:0;background-size:cover;
       background-image:url(my.svg);" />
```

I have also tried

```css
 background-size:contain;
 background-size:cover;
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-postion: center center;
```

but no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I scale a stubborn svg embedded with the <object> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644896/how-do-i-scale-a-stubborn-svg-embedded-with-the-object-tag)

Comment: Where in my post is an `<object>` tag?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I got this to work in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari using

```
<img src="my.svg" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;" />
```

The trick was to make sure the SVG I was displaying had preserveAspectRatio="none" set in the root.  Also, I had to either delete the viewBox in the SVG, or make sure it tightly cropped the image content.

For example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 5 3">
    <desc>Flag of Germany</desc>
    <rect id="black_stripe" width="5" height="3" y="0" x="0" fill="#000"/>
    <rect id="red_stripe" width="5" height="2" y="1" x="0" fill="#D00"/>
    <rect id="gold_stripe" width="5" height="1" y="2" x="0" fill="#FFCE00"/>
</svg>
```

Hopefully you have control over the content of the SVG files you are trying to display. :-)

Comment: This worked perfect. Apparently it was Adobe Illustrator that was messing with me!

Comment: The `preserveAspectRatio="none"` tip really saved me. Thanks!

Comment: For others, note that obviously position:fixed should be position: absolute if you want this to live inside a parent.

Comment: preserveAspectRatio="none" - THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jQuery solution.  As you can see, I'm using it with an SVG without `<svg>`

The css

```
#bgImage{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

The html

```
<object width="10" height="10" id="bgImage" data="resources/runner.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

The javascript

```
//resize the background image
function resizeImage($selection){
    //get the ratio of the image
    var imageRatio = $selection.width() / $selection.height();

    //get the screen ratio
    var screenRatio = $(window).width() / $(window).height();

    //if the image is wider than the screen
    if(imageRatio > screenRatio){
        $selection.height($(window).height()); //set image height to screen height
        $selection.width($(window).height()*imageRatio); //set the correct width based on image ratio
    }

    //if the screen is wider than the image
    else{
        $selection.width($(window).width()); //set the image width to the screen width
        $selection.height($(window).width()/imageRatio); //set the correct image height based on the image ratio
    }
}
```

Run this whenever you want to resize the image, typically on "onresize" and "onload"

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    resizeImage($("#bgImage"));
}
```

Comment: Fix?  I'm hesitant to remove the jQuery selection parameter, since I like the flexibility of this.  I suppose just calling resizeImage() would be easier, but more constrained.