# Making inline svg fill whole screen

Tags: html, css, svg

I have bought an svg graphics, which I have exported to .svg file, so that it can be used in inline HTML. I have inserted it into `<body>` tag of my document, but now I want it to fill full width and full height of the screen. I have tried setting width and height attribute of `<svg>`, `position: absolute` and `top, right, bottom, left: 0`, `viewBox` set to `"0 0 screen_width screen_height"`, load .svg file as image and force image to be full-window using `position: absolute` nad `top, right, bottom, left: 0`.
Nothing worked, though.

Here is the svg itself: http://pastebin.com/y8kqf1bD

I have tried all of the options from [Full width and height SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382434/full-width-and-height-svg) but they do not work, too.

Do you have an idea how could I do that?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Remember! ViewBox is not how big it is. ViewBox is actually the opposite of how big it is. ViewBox is how big it is at the native size. Increasing the ViewBox width will _decrease_ the size width.

Comment: also make sure to set [**`preserveAspectRatio`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`<svg>` elements are sized using height and width attributes so

```
<svg height="100%" width="100%">
</svg>
```

will fill the screen.

You will additionally need to set both the `<html>` and `<body>` tags style="width:100%;height:100%" to ensure that they cover the screen. Here's a complete full screen rect:

```html
<html style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<body style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;">
  <svg height="100%" width="100%">
    <rect fill="lime" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also do this via a stylesheet if you want.

```css
html, body, svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <svg>
    <rect fill="lime" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```