# How to change the width of an svg rect with css

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

Is is possible to change width of SVG rectangle with CSS?

This doesn't work:

```
#red {
    width: 800px;
}
#red:hover {
    width: 1600px;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJLCg/).

Comment: yes, you can do, check this example ..http://blog.studio.gd/blog/id/10/how_to_style_svg_with_css_-_part_2-3

Comment: Thanks, with scale it could work but the position isn't right: http://jsfiddle.net/fJLCg/17/

Answer (score 12):

Since the `width` css property doesn't (yet) apply to `<rect>` elements you can't do it like in your question.

However, you can make it work by using units that depend on some other css property.

Like this, svg:

```
<rect id="red" width="1em" fill="red" height="270" />
```

and CSS:

```
#red {
    font-size: 800px;
}
#red:hover {
    font-size: 1600px;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uH6j5/).

To answer the followup question, "how do you do this if you want to grow the height (or width) in the opposite direction?", here's one way:

Flip the coordinate system using `transform="scale(1,-1)"` (adjusting the other values to go along with that, e.g negative `y` coordinate position).

```
<rect id="red" y="-515.5" width="270" height="2em" transform="scale(1,-1)"/>
```

and CSS:

```
#red:hover {    
    animation: scaleheight 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes scaleheight {
    0% {
         fill:red;
    }
    100% {
         fill:blue;
         font-size: 300px;
    }
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GL95J/).

Comment: Oh, this looks good :) Would it possible to change „height“ – bottom to top as well?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry ;) I mean, would it possible to scale from bottom to top? Like this but in the another direction? http://jsfiddle.net/uH6j5/3/

Comment: Great solution, thanks! I created an example that uses an image pattern and percentage values, based on your solution - https://codepen.io/TheRemoteCoder/pen/JjKwWxd

Answer (score 0):

I've made some SVG animation for you. Check the below link shows examples like `SVG Scaling`and `SVG element Movement`. As example shows you can create many `rec` and animate them as way you want.

Check the Update Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/CasPj/11/

Comment: Looks good, but it should change the height or with of a rectangle like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fJLCg/17/

Comment: okay, do you want this way? please check the updated fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/CasPj/11/

Answer (score -1):

Yes, its possible. Make an svg file with a rectangle, and then import it to your html with img tag.

See: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382434/full-width-and-height-svg)

Comment: Okay, but if I have 30 rectangles I've to create 30 SVG files and import in my html as img tag? Is there any other solution to transform the size with IDs?

Comment: You would make a single svg and use <img>  30 times.