# Responsive svg not getting full width in safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari

I have a svg that should be 100% width of the body, and it works in ie11, chrome and firefox - but in safari there's some space at both sides of the svg and I cannot get rid of it. Any help appreciated - see the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tbbtester/2apEh/

The css:

```
body{margin:0;padding:0;background:orange;}
.top {position: absolute;width: 100%;}
.inner{height:0;position: relative;padding-top:3.2%;}
svg{height: 100%;display:block;width: 100%;position: absolute;top:0;left:0;}
rect{stroke:none;fill:teal;}
```

The markup:

```
    <div class="top">
        <div class="inner">
            <svg viewBox='0 0 100 3.2' preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                <rect x="0" y="0" height="3.2" width="100"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On referring to this

[Previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382434/full-width-and-height-svg)

it seems that this

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
```

is the issue.

If you change it to

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

the problem is solved

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2apEh/9/)

Answer (score 0):

`preserveAspectRatio` attribute can have 3 different kind of value `meet` `slice` `none`. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/furisexo/2/edit)**.

so if you use

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 100 3.2' preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid none">
```

instead of

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 100 3.2' preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
```

you problem might solve.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a set width and height of `100%` on the SVG element fixed it on Safari for me.