# How to Resize SVG to different sizes

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, svg, jquery-svg

I am using [Jquery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) plugin in my project. I want to resize my svg to different sizes
I have written following code to load svg in smaller size

```
 $('#svgbasics').svg({
            loadURL: 'lion.svg', // External document to load 
            onLoad: null, // Callback once loaded 
            settings: {width: '100px'}, // Additional settings for SVG element 
            initPath: ''
        })
```

but it always open image in 100% size, Anyone please help me how can i show SVG in different sizes

Comment: What is the width setting for the #svgbasics element?

Comment: thats what i am confused that how can i set width , height and viewBox

Comment: `$('#svgbasics').css('width','100px');`

Comment: in this way div is resized but SVG remain same size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after searching for days i find out following things

> if you want to resize your svg then we have to resize viewbox of svg, setting width will only resize outer display area

we can resize svg by simply displaying it in image tag and resize it according to requirement
i.e.

```
<img width="200px" src="lion.svg"></img>
```

i found answer in following post

[How do I scale a stubborn SVG embedded with the <object> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644896/how-do-i-scale-a-stubborn-svg-embedded-with-the-object-tag)

Comment: it's better to use object, embed or iframe: you get the same result but you can also manipulate the svg inner dom (as explained in the link you mentioned)