# How to embed a SVG object filling the container element

Tags: html, svg

I have a SVG file `file.svg` (converted from a pdf) embedded in a DOM object (td element). I want it to stretch to fill the container element. I tried

```
<td><object data="file.svg" type="image/svg+xml" max-width="100%"></object></td>
```

which displays it too big (probably the size of the default size of the file), and if I do

```
<td><object data="file.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%"></object></td>
```

then it displays too small. What is the correct way to set the size so that it fills up the td element? Will it be easier if I use an external library like raphael.js, or is there a different way of embedding?

Answer (score 1):

A quick fast comment from me.  Did you forget the equal sign?

```
width "100%"
max-width "100%"
```

Maybe try this, it works for me.

```
<img src="file.svg" style="width:100%;height:100%;" />
```

Comment: Yea it happnes hehe, can you btw send me that file.svg file or link it here so i can test it real quick? :)

Comment: or actually, can you make a zip file and put it on some site so i can get it with all the code plase :)

Comment: Maybe also if you read this it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644896/how-do-i-scale-a-stubborn-svg-embedded-with-the-object-tag